# Price filter shows prices excluding taxes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a Woocommerce and I use code for showing prices including tax (21%).
In Woocommerce backend I have set up that I am inserting prices excluding tax and tax are automatically counted.

The issue is when you filter by price. The prices in filter starts with prices excluding tax.
So customer see the lowest price 3800,- Kč but with taxes it is 4599,- Kč.

The url of issue: https://dostupnyiphone.cz/kategorie/nove/

Do you have any idea how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

The code:

```
<?
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;

// Get the prices
$price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ); // price without VAT
$price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product );  // price with VAT
$tax_amount     = $price_incl_tax - $price_excl_tax; // VAT amount

// Display the prices
?>
<p class="price product-page-price"><span class="s-dph">Cena s DPH</span><?php echo wc_price( $price_incl_tax ); ?></p>
<p class="price product-page-price"><span class="bez-dph">Cena bez DPH</span><?php echo wc_price( $price_excl_tax ); ?></p>
```

[image: issue]

Comment: Ok. How does your code look like and where do you put your code?

Comment: Please provide some code to check what's not working.

Comment: I edited the post and added the code.
However the code is only for displaying prices including taxes on single product page.
It has nothing to do with filtering where is the issue.